# Why are my vfptr table entries mixed up?

Tags: c++, virtual, vtable

I'm stumped on the following issue (MSVC++ 2012):

I have a set of pure virtual classes that define interfaces and some derived classes with multiple inheritance for implementation. I use the same set of base classes for the implementation of two different end classes (in the class hierarchy that follows, the "Foo" class implements the virtual functions differently for each of those two end classes). One of those two end classes compiles without issues but the other one has its vfptr table entries mixed up. I'm puzzled at what may be causing this and haven't been able to point at the error. So I submit this to the C++ experts here.

Here is the class hierarchy in a simplified way:

```
class IBaz1 {
   virtual void IBaz1_SC() = 0;
   virtual void IBaz1_IVR() = 0;
   virtual void IBaz1_ICIVR() = 0;
};

class IBaz2 {
   virtual void IBaz2_JTHL() = 0;
   virtual void IBaz2_UP() = 0;
   virtual void IBaz2_RKF() = 0;
   virtual void IBaz2_GVC() = 0;
   virtual void IBaz2_GAI() = 0;
};

class IBaz3 {
   virtual void IBaz3_SCJ() = 0;
   virtual void IBaz3_CJS() = 0;
};

class IQux {
   virtual void IQux_RIU() = 0;
   virtual void IQux_CTAU() = 0;
   virtual void IQux_D() = 0;
   virtual void IQux_AD() = 0;
   virtual void IQux_IDIP() = 0;
   virtual void IQux_GLT() = 0;
   virtual void IQux_SLT() = 0;
   virtual void IQux_GF() = 0;
};

class Qux : public IQux {
   virtual void Qux::IQux_D();
   virtual void Qux::IQux_AD();
   virtual void Qux::IQux_IDIP();
};

class Bar : public IBaz1, public IBaz2, public IBaz3, public Qux {
   virtual void IBaz1_ICIVR();
   virtual void IBaz2_UP();
   virtual void IQux_RIU();
   virtual void IQux_GLT();
   virtual void IQux_SLT();
   virtual void IQux_GF();
};

class FooA (and FooB) : public Bar {
   virtual void IBaz1_SC();
   virtual void IBaz1_IVR();
   virtual void IBaz2_JTHL();
   virtual void IBaz2_RKF();
   virtual void IBaz2_GVC();
   virtual void IBaz2_GAI();
   virtual void IBaz3_SCJ();
   virtual void IBaz3_CJS();
   virtual void IQux_CTAU();
};

      Expected vfptr             result mixed-up vfptr
      ======================     ====================================
FooA (is also a COM)       FooB (is a straight inheritance)
  Bar                        Bar
    IBaz1                      IBaz1
      [0] Foo::IBaz1_SC()        [0] Foo::IBaz1_SC()
      [1] Foo::IBaz1_IVR()       [1] Foo::IBaz1_IVR()
      [2] Bar::IBaz1_ICIVR()     [2] Bar::IBaz1_ICIVR()
    IBaz2                      IBaz2
      [0] Foo::IBaz2_JTHL()      [0] Bar::IQux_GLT()
      [1] Bar::IBaz2_UP()        [1] Bar::IQux_SLT()
      [2] Foo::IBaz2_RKF()       [2] Foo::IBaz2_JTHL()
      [3] Foo::IBaz2_GVC()       [3] Bar::IBaz2_UP()
      [4] Foo::IBaz2_GAI()       [4] Foo::IBaz2_RKF()
    IBaz3                      IBaz3
      [0] Foo::IBaz3_SCJ()       [0] Foo::IBaz3_SCJ()
      [1] Foo::IBaz3_CJS()       [1] Foo::IBaz3_CJS()
    Qux                        Qux
      IQux                       IQux
        [0] Bar::IQux_RIU()        [0] Bar::IQux_RIU()
        [1] Foo::IQux_CTAU()       [1] Foo::IQux_CTAU()
        [2] Qux::IQux_D()          [2] Qux::IQux_D()
        [3] Qux::IQux_AD()         [3] Qux::IQux_AD()
        [4] Qux::IQux_IDIP()       [4] Qux::IQux_IDIP()
        [5] Bar::IQux_GLT()        [5] [thunk]:Bar::IQux_GLT`adjustor{8}'()
        [6] Bar::IQux_SLT()        [6] [thunk]:Bar::IQux_SLT`adjustor{8}'()
        [7] Bar::IQux_GF()         [7] [thunk]:Bar::IQux_GF`adjustor{8}'()
```

The two end classes are "FooA" and "FooB". In the real code, they are defined the same way except that FooA is also an AxtiveX COM object so in addition to being inheriting from Bar, and thus from IBaz1, IBaz2, IBaz3 and Qux, it also inherits from a lot of ATL templates.

I have reduced the names to their capitals so they fit in a page width. For instance the true name of IBaz1_SC is "SetCapture" in the real code, and IBaz1_IVR true name is "InvalidateViewportRect".

I show the two vfptr tables side by side so they can be easily compared. The vfptr table layout I show is the layout I get from MSVC debugger "Auto" window after I have expanded the vtable for all the inherited classes. The left vfptr tables are from the end class that builds and runs fine, that is "FooA", which is also a COM inherited class. While the right vfptr table are from the end class that does not run, that is "FooB", which is *not* a COM inherited class but only a straight inherited class.

Notice the entries in IBaz2 vfptr. The pointer in IBaz2[0] have been pushed down to IBaz2[2], and IBaz2[1] to IBaz2[3], etc. And the entries in IBaz2[0] and [1] point to functions from IQuz[5] and [6]. And now the pointers in IQux[5] to [7] are going through a thunk and have an adjustor.

The program crashes when at some point, it calls IBaz2_JTHL instead of calling IBaz2_RKF.

What may be causing this? What kind of coding errors should I be looking for? Any explanations that might help understand the issue and solve this problem will be greatlly appreciated.

I can supply better code extracts if required.

Comment: Something tells me your issue is in the final class code that you haven't posted, if it works for one and not the other why don't you try posting the class that doesn't work? On an unrelated note, none of your classes have a `virtual` destructor, this is dangerous unless you only use objects on the stack.

Comment: Sorry, for me the code is nearly unreadable. Is it possible to minimize the example to a point where the reader is able to catch the problem, if there is really one? Unreadable names in the source are the first step to broken code.

Comment: "has its vfptr table entries mixed up". That's your interpretation of facts. Let's look at the facts themselves first. You are not presenting them. If your program has unexpected behaviour, describe the expected and actual behaviour, and show the complete source so that it can be reproduced.

Comment: Why don't you have virtual destructors?

Comment: I have edited the OP in trying to make more explcit the two enc classes, explain the names used in the example (this is not just a toy example, this is from a real application with hundred of thousand of lines of code, just the real classes involved would be several pages long), and make it more explicit the expected results vs the obtained results.

Comment: [I could not find how to edit a comment] I also added in the OP an explanation as to where and how the program crashes. And I'll add a virtual destructor.

Comment: All of the methods in base classes are pure virtual. Why should they appear in vtables at all? (I have no experience in examining vtables; this should be easy to answer)

Comment: @anatolyg: Because you can still call them.

Answer (score 2):

So I found the cause of this vtable mixup. The class IBaz2 was defined twice. The second definition was in an old source file that had been removed from the project a while ago but was still on disk and referenced in a precompiled header.

This second and old definition had all the pure virtual functions that were shown in the wrong vtable. I assume that, because it was in a precompiled header, the old definition was used for the vtable layout at compile time but the code to access it was generated from the new definition.

In order to figure that, I started renaming the involved classes. While fixing the renaming related issues, I stumbled on this reference to the old file.

Now everything works as expected. I would have expected that the compiler would complain about the class second definition though.

Answer (score 1):

From the question as posed, it's only clear that the resulting vtable layout doesn't match your expectations. That's most likely due to your expectations than anything else.

The adjustor thunks are typically caused by base classes at non-zero offsets, which in turn are caused by multiple inheritance.

MSVC is known to fold identical functions, which may cause confusion. E.g if some of these functions are no-ops, their vtable entries may all point to the same no-op implementation.

That your code doesn't run is probably because you're bypassing C++ and accessing the vtable directly (I assume this because you show a vtable layout, which isn't even defined in the C++ Standard)

**[edit]**

The new information pretty much confirms it: non-standard access = COM. COM is less powerful than C++ and cannot deal with multiple inheritance. COM misinterprets the vtables from C++ classes that do use MI, causing the kind of issues seen above.

Comment: Thanks for the "no-op" indication. I'll check that. I don't access the vtable directly. The layouts I show, side by side are the ones I see in the debugger whem I expand the pointers to the vtables.

Comment: Well, COM accesses them for you. Same problem in the end.

Comment: It is the COM inherited FooA that runs smoothly. The straight, non-COM FooB is the one that has its vtable mixed-up. I'm editing the OP to make this more explicit. Also, none of the pure virtual functions are exposed in the COM interface. They are only called internally.